# How to compute probabilities instead of actual classifications on ML problems

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

Let's assume that we have a few data points that can be used as the training set. Each row is consisted of 4 say columns (features) that take boolean values. The 5th column expresses the class and it also takes boolean values. Here is an example (they are almost random):

```
1,1,1,0,1
0,1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

Now, what I want to do is to build a model such that for any given input (new line) the system does not return the class itself (like in the case of a regular classification problem) but instead the probability this particular input belongs to class 0 or class 1. How can I do that? What's more, how can I generate a confidence interval or error rate associated with that computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all classification algorithms return probabilities, because not all of them have an underlying probabilistic model. For example, a classification tree is just a set of rules that you follow to assign each new input to a particular class.

An example of a classification algorithm that *does* have an underlying probabilistic model is logistic regression. In this algorithm, the probability that a particular input `x` is in the class is

```
prob = 1 / (1 + exp( -theta * x ))
```

where theta is a vector of coefficients with the same number of dimensions as `x`. Generally to move from probabilities to classifications, you simply threshold, e.g.

```
if prob < 0.5
  return 0;
else
  return 1;
end
```

Other classification algorithms *may* have probabilistic interpretations, for example random forests are essentially a voting algorithm with multiple classification trees. If 80% of the trees vote for class 1 and 20% vote for class 2, then you could output an 80% probability of being in class 1. But this is a side effect of how the model works, rather than an explicit underlying probability model.